# Stuck on eloquent relationships - pivot and polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, schema, laravel-5, relationships

Hello I am stuck on trying to get all comments that belong to a user where a pivot is in between these 2 models. I can't seem to wrap my head around it or my database schema could just be plain wrong. Anyways I would love some help.

Currently my models look like this:

**User.php**

```
class User extends Model 
{
    // Grab all the beers that this user has checked in to his personal profile
    public function beers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Beer')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('rating', 'description');
    }
}
```

**Beer.php(pivot relationship)**

```
class Beer extends Model
{
    // polymorphic relationship grab all comments that belong to this beer
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

**Comment.php(set up as polymorphic)**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

The code here grabs all the comments that belong to a beer pivot record. This works perfectly fine because $user->beers takes into account that we are dealing with a specific user profile and only finds pivot records from the specific $user.

```
$user = User::find($id);

@foreach($user->beers as $beer)
    @foreach($beer->comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Unfortunately  the comments relationship only looks at the commentable_id  and commentable_type from the comments table and does not take into account the current user_id(the profile we are currently viewing) so when I look at another profile of a user that has the same beer_user pivot combination on his profile the same comments show up there as well.

How can I call the comments relationship of my Beer.php model so that I take into account the user_id as well? Obviously I already added a user_id to my comments table. I've tried to ask this before but I hope by being a bit more detailed this time people can help me out now, I also know how to finally formulate this problem a bit better.

Database:

[image]

Comment: did you try to chain your query such as $beer->comments()->where('user_id', '=', $user->id) ? By the way, do you intend to have Comments of Users? If you are just willing to make Comments available for Beers by Users, you don't need morph relationships.

Comment: I don'g get it. What is you query that you want to implement ?

Comment: Grab all beers that belong to a specific user and then grab all the comments that are placed on that user's beers. When I perform the query from my example it works but the query does not factor in the pivot record beer_id/user_id combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific code example, I would just use eager loading with a constraint on the user id:

```
$user = User::with(['beers', 'beers.comments' => function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('id', $id);
    });
}])->find($id);

@foreach($user->beers as $beer)
    @foreach($beer->comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This eager loading constraint will only work when you have the user's id ahead of time.

Imagine, however, you weren't able to constrain the eager loading or the query to get the comments. You could still filter the comments Collection after the fact:

```
@foreach($user->beers as $beer)
    @foreach($beer->comments->where('user_id', $user->id) as $comment)
    {{ $comment }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was already figuring out on how to add a where clause to the foreach loop. I tried doing stupid stuff like passing a parameter to the relationship but in the end it's just as simple as adding a where clause. Of course I will stick with eager loading though but thanks you so much, so much for your help. Was stuck on this problem for longer than I would like to admit haha.

Comment: I realised this is still not exactly what I am looking for after further testing. The query you provided checks for the user_id in the comment table but I need to check for the user_id on the beer_user pivot table.

The user_id from the comment table just tells which user posted this comment. I need to be able to comment on a certain beer_id, user_id combination of my pivot table and just just search for a beer_id when I input App\Beer as a commentable_type. Thank for your help though.